# How to authenticate a SOAP service using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I tried to authenticate the following request using PHP but its not working

Here is my following SOAP request

```
POST /BCWebservice/BCWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: service.bcstaging.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.bcstaging.com/bc/Authenticate"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Authenticate xmlns="http://www.bcstaging.com/bc">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <version>string</version>
      <eaCode>int</eaCode>
    </Authenticate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
    $soapURL = "http://service.bcstaging.com/BCWebService.asmx?wsdl";
    $soapParameters = array(
        'Username' => $username,
        'Password' => $password,
        'ProductVersion' => '2.9.0.0',
        'EACode' => $eaCode
        );
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($soapURL);
   $objResponse = $soapClient->__soapCall('Authenticate', $soapParameters);
```

And I got the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It's not working" tells us next to nothing about what _exactly_ is going wrong here. Are you experiencing some sort of incorrect behaviour? You get a run-time error? Your computer gained sentience and is attempting to take over the world? Details man! Details!

Comment: @Aiken : updated regarding the issue

Comment: could you post your soap server, its seem your $soapParameters need to be an object. try to make instance object `$soapParameters = new stdClass();
$soapParameters->Username= $username;
$soapParameters->Password= $password;
$soapParameters->ProductVersion= '2.9.0.0';
$soapParameters->EACode= $eaCode;` and try call your soap client `$objResponse = $soapClient->__soapCall('Authenticate', $soapParameters);`

Comment: Please don't harass people in comments by pinging them multiple times. No one will dare to help you with your questions anymore if you continue doing that.